# How to write xpath for grand child siblings

Tags: selenium, xpath, rows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oLR4.png)On a page I have a row, I wanted to delete the row based on the row data, i.e if I have multiple rows, I can delete the row based on the row (cell) data

I am able to read the data, also I am able to identify the delete button separately.

But the challenge is, if I have more than one row then I get more than 1 matching for delete button.

So I wanted to delete the row based on the cell data.

When I try with parent<<>> child node logic i couldn't able to find the delete button based on the row data.

below are the xpaths which i tried, can someone pls suggest me how to get correct `xpath`.

`xpath` to find row data:

```
//div[@class='ui-grid-draggable-row ng-scope ng-isolate-scope']/div/div[contains(@title,'ART_Location')]
```

`xpath` to find delete button:

```
//div[@class='ui-grid-draggable-row ng-scope ng-isolate-scope']/div/div/button[@class='delete-data-collectors-monitor']
```

if i combine both xpaths (row data with delete)

```
xpath= //div[@class='ui-grid-draggable-row ng-scope ng-isolate-scope']/div/div[contains(@title,'ART_Location')]/../button[@class='delete-data-collectors-monitor']
```

here i am not getting the delete button identified, pls suggest.

Comment: `//div[@class='ui-grid-draggable-row ng-scope ng-isolate-scope' and contains(div/div/@title,'ART_Location')]/div/div/button[@class='delete-data-collectors-monitor']`

Comment: Thank you splash for your comment, i couldnt able to get the element. but if i got back to parent class using /../.. then i am able to hit button
//div[@class='ui-grid-draggable-row ng-scope ng-isolate-scope']/div/div[@title='ART_Location']/../../div/div/button[@class='delete-data']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below `xpath`.

```
.//div[text()='ART_Location']/../..//button[@class='<class name of the button>']
```

If your delete button is in the last column, then use the below `xpath`:

```
.//div[text()='ART_Location']/../div[last()]/div/button[@class='<class name of the button>']
```

If your delete button is present at a particular position then use below `xpath`:

```
.//div[text()='ART_Location']/../following-sibling::div[position()=<position number from the ART_Location div>]/div/button
```

Hope this helps.